# Facebook sharing event answer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

In facebook API 2.0, I found all the information how to create a Share button, but no information on how to find out whether the user shared or not? I found an option for the old API, but in the new it does not work. 
Someone know? Is it possible and how?
I need to get the information the given user shared post/info from the site or not.
Thanks.

Comment: what for do you need to know? what´s the point of knowing?

Comment: It is necessary to add to the database those who made sharing.

Comment: we know that, but WHAT FOR exactly? what is the use case? what will you do with the info? i guess you don`t want to get the info just for storing it, because that would be pointless.

Comment: Only for storing. If you share - you can register. So some callback url or info about sharing.

Comment: only for storing is not a valid use case. in that case, there is no possibility.